# PostgreSQL Replication for small, low-usage database

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have PostgreSQL 8.4 installed on a headless Ubuntu 10.04 server. Sometimes the server is not available. I would like to continue working on the database, so I thought of installing PostgreSQL onto my laptop. I'm familiar with PostgreSQL, but not with replication. Would I setup *replication* so that the two databases are kept synchronized when the server becomes available again? This does not need to be automated. What is the easiest and simplest approach? The database is not used extensively by others at this stage and is small, so a simple, lightweight solution would be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, one of these may be suitable:

- [Bucardo](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bucardo)
- [Londiste](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Londiste_Tutorial)
- [RubyRep](http://www.rubyrep.org)
- [Slony](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slony)

A general discussion of replication and clustering in PostgreSQL is [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling).

There are also many questions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=postgresql+replication) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/11137/postgresql-replication) useful one on ServerFault.

Comment: An update to to 9.1 which offers out-of-the-box asynchronous and synchronous replication is also an option.

Comment: I considered that. Ubuntu 10.04 provides PostgreSQL version 8.4 from the repositories. I don't know how involved installing a different version would be.

Comment: I will never understand why Linux makes it so hard to install up-to-date software. Can't you just download the RPM's (or whatever is needed for Ubuntu) from the Postgres website?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04 is a long-term support (LTS) release. Ubuntu, like most distributions, provides versions of software in the repositories for "easy" installation. The paradigm is different to Windows. Other versions of Debian (testing/unstable) and other distributions provide "always-updated" rolling releases which will have the latest versions of software. This is *not* what you would want on a server though, where you *want* stability. The next LTS release of Ubuntu, released recently, includes PostgreSQL 9. This would be the natural upgrade route.

Comment: Not that I'm about to upgrade "just" for replication functionality, but here is a link for .deb packages for PostgreSQL 9: http://www.openscg.com/se/postgresql/packages.jsp

Comment: Go to https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql and click on "Read about installing". From there it's about 3 commands to type in a console. This is the official method that Ubuntu folks would recommend.

Comment: @SabreWolfy: having to upgrade the whole operating system just to upgrade one component (yet an important one) seems silly to me - especially with regards to stability (btw: there are a lot more reasons than just replication that justify a PG upgrade)

Comment: @DanielVérité: Thanks. That's very useful to know.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I agree that upgrading to PostgreSQL 9 will bring a range of other benefits of course. Just like upgrading the OS will bring a range of other improvements, not just the database server. I don't think we should launch into a discussion about Linux upgrades though, as it is not relevant.